# How to insert a decimal value to money data type column with wpf C# and Ado.Net Data Entity

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to save prices for products from a textbox. I know I have to convert or parse the input into decimal datatype. Now I have two question about this:

1. How to make the output format (when it shows the price in the datagrid) fit my need, to show only two digits after the "," or "."?
2. what's the best way to set the price with cents? to make 2 textboxes and concat them somehow or set it manually from just 1 textbox? if the second case, how to make the textbox only allow numbers with "," or "." and just 2 digits after the comma or point?

Hope my questions are clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a style for your TextBoxes. Here's a basic style that should provide you with enough information to research the terms included so you can alter it to act how you want. You may need to bind a Path.

```
<Style x:Key="MoneyStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding StringFormat='###,###.##'"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: You answered my second question. Can you also give me any idea how to do the first also?

Comment: As Path do I have to use the database table attribute or the txtBox name?

Comment: For the path you would use the table attribute. You can apply a similar style to your datagrid editors so that when it displays the numbers are formatted correctly.